# Azure webapp diagnostic tool - Availability report

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics

I see there is a feature in the azure-web app that shows a web-app down graph within the diagnostic tools. But it only shows the last 24 hours. Can we retrieve larger date intervals? last 7 days or even the last 30 days from the log analytics?

[image: Azure web app down graph]

Comment: You can view and change the timeframe from 1h,6h,1d only on Diagnostic blade. 
You may sign in to your Kudu website (https://*yourwebsitename*.scm.azurewebsites.net) to fetch more details about the logs.

-The Filesystem option is for temporary debugging purposes, and turns itself off in 12 hours, you can enable Azure storage Blob for long term storage - See this doc for logging info - https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files

Comment: I can not change the timeframe. It says "Difference between start and end date times should not be more than 24 hours."

Comment: Instead of having the logs, I would see the availability as graph as the diagnostic tool shows

Comment: @arifcoskun Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Azure App Service Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) experience is the most helpful to diagnose any issues within a 24-hour timeframe over a period of 30 days.

Although you could configure your web app to integrate with Azure Log Analytics via [diagnostic settings](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/11/01/App-Service-Integration-with-Azure-Monitor.html) or configure [Health Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check) to monitor/ensure availability of your web app, I would highly recommend leveraging Azure Application Insights for all your monitoring needs.

[Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) not only includes powerful analytics tools to help you diagnose issues, but also automatically detects performance anomalies backed by rich telemetry. It is designed to help you continuously improve performance and usability of your application.

And interestingly enough, you can also [integrate App Insights with App Service Diagnostics](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/04/21/Announcing-Application-Insights-Integration-with-App-Service-Diagnostics.html). :)

App Service Diagnostics would then start leveraging App Insights telemetry and point you to exceptions and dependency slowness information in different views that you typically use to diagnose issues.